# Issue converting CSV files to point shapefiles using pyqgis - QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, convert, qgis-3, csv

I have hit a snag using pyqgis in QGIS 3. I want to convert a set of CSVs (20 total) into point shapefiles but I am struggling with just the single CSV case. My code is based on this blogpost (https://www.geodose.com/2018/07/python-qgis-tutorial-adding-csv-data.html). I keep getting the same error but the "reason" section of the error message is always empty.

#### My code:

This is the full code, I have not imported any additional packages.

```
path = "C:/Users/.../Weather/CSVs/precip_1992.csv"
uri = path + "?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "longitude", "latitude","epsg:4326")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'Points', 'delimitedtext')
print(vlayer.isValid())

iface.addVectorLayer(uri,'Points','delimitedtext')
```

The error message in the "messages" log:

```
    2019-03-13T15:23:27     CRITICAL    Layer is not valid : The layer 
    C:/Users/.../CSVs/precip_1992.csv?encoding=UTF-8&delimiter=,&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&crs=epsg:4326 is not a valid
 layer and can not be added to the map. Reason:
```

The error message in the "delimited" log:

```
    2019-03-13T15:27:59     WARNING    
File cannot be opened or delimiter parameters are not valid
```

#### Sample of my csv file:

```
longitude,latitude,year,sum_precip,avg_precip
-179.75,71.25,1992,150.3,12.525001
-179.75,68.75,1992,189.5,15.791667
-179.75,68.25,1992,226.7,18.891666
-179.75,67.75,1992,287.10001,23.925001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix the path with `file:///`, this is due to QGIS using the [file URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) when locating files.

So replace:

```
path = "C:/Users/.../Weather/CSVs/precip_1992.csv"
```

with:

```
path = "file:///C:/Users/.../Weather/CSVs/precip_1992.csv"
```

[image: Example]

---

Your layer should now be valid (tested with QGIS 3.4).

Comment: Dear @Joseph, do you know why `file:///` requires three slashes?

Comment: @Taras - The provider string is based on the [file URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) so in order to access locally stored files, the path needs to be prefixed with the mentioned syntax.